# Thermal radiation in the Unruh Effect

Tags: general-relativity, statistical-mechanics, black-holes, density-operator, unruh-effect

The following formula has been given in 't Hooft's black holes notes ($|\Omega \rangle$ is the vacuum state of Minkowski space, O is a operator):

$$\langle \Omega| O|\Omega \rangle = \sum_{n \ge 0} \langle n | O | n \rangle e^{-2 \pi n \omega}(1-e^{-2 \pi \omega})=Tr(O \rho_{\Omega})$$

**How does this mean that the radiation is thermal and follows Plancks black body law?**

1. [Here](https://www.gl.ciw.edu/static/users/bmilitzer/diss/node13.html), I read that $\langle O \rangle = \frac{1}{Z}\sum_n e^{-\beta E_n}\langle n |O|n\rangle$. How is this sum the same as that in the above expression?
2. How is the density matrix related to the law of black body radiation? How can I derive Planck's law from the expectation value of O in the first expression?

Comment: $(1-e^{-2 \pi \omega})$ does not depends on $n$, so we don't care, it will be absorbed in the definition of $Z$

Answer (score 1):

First, let's see the density matrix of thermal mixture (in some cases is the Planck's law):
$$
\rho_{Thermal}=\frac{1}{Z}\sum_{n=0}^{N}e^{-\beta E_n}|n\rangle \langle n|
$$

Now we note that the expectation value $\langle \Omega|O|\Omega \rangle$ is equal to
$$
\frac{1}{Z}\sum_{n=0}^{N}e^{-\beta E_n}\langle n|O|n \rangle ,
$$

with $Z=(1-e^{-2 \pi \omega})^{-1}$ and $\beta E_n=2 \pi n \omega$ (this expression give us the $\beta$).

The operator $O$ in $|n\rangle 's$ basis is simple a matrix $O_{nm}=\langle n|O| m\rangle$. Now is easy to see that $\langle \Omega| O|\Omega \rangle = Tr(O \rho_{Thermal})=$ 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N}O_{n}\frac{e^{-\beta E_n}}{Z}.
$$.